# Tomcat 7 config

Tags: windows, tomcat, config

Just trying to get fancy. I know I can do this by creating an app and putting a getQueryParam into a jsp file and forward like that.

But I wanted to see if this is possible.

I am working on an application that points to an xml datasource. So the URL on the server is simply "/safe" because it uses the app URL to go to (domain.com/safe). What I wanted to see if it was possible to create a mapping in tomcat 7 that allows (localhost/safe) to be forwarded or treated like (domain.com/safe).

so when editing my application locally I don't have to change the httpService back and forth

Comment: I suggest reading about Internet technologies. This question does not have a clearly defined scope.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to configure is virtual hosting. Read about [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) and the [Host](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html) container in the official Tomcat documentation.

Comment: I have read this its similar to IIS virtual hosts, thats not quite what I am trying to do , let me try to explain this a little better since I was on a cell phone writing that.

I have an application that points to a datasource (XML) the local reference on the server is simply /safe because it uses the application root on the server to reference domain.com/safe. 

I want to be able to edit this application without the need to change that reference so I want to try to get my local (localhost/safe) to point to (domain.com/safe) 

Now when I can test my app locally without changing the file